# Studying the convergence of $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{\cosh(i\frac{\pi}{n})}}{n^{\log n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Study the convergence of the following series:$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{\cosh(i\frac{\pi}{n})}}{n^{\log n}}$$

Using Weierstrass comparison test
$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{\cosh(i\frac{\pi}{n})}}{n^{\log n}}=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}}{n^{\log n}}\leqslant \sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\log n}}$

I do not know how to evaluate the latest series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\log n}}$

I thought also of apllying Diriclet test to $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}}{n^{\log n}}$ once $|{\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}|<1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\log n}}=0$

**Questions:**

Can someone give me a hint?

Is it correct to use Dirichlet test?

Comment: You don't need to evaluate the series. Just note $\log n\geq 2$ for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\log n>2\quad,\quad n>100$$therefore$$n^{\log n}>n^2\to 0<{1\over n^{\log n}}<{1\over n^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\cosh(i\pi/n)=\cos(\pi/n)$ so that it is sufficient to prove the convergence of $\sum n^{-\log n}$. Try using the comparison on this series (see also Wojowu's comment).